# Getting a parents children through a backref attribute via sqlalchemy relationship causes unnecessary flush

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlalchemy relationship like this (trimmed for simplicity):

```
class Parent(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'Parent'
  name = Column(String, nullable=False)
  def __init__(self, name)
    self.name = name

class Child(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'Child'
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    parent = relationship(Parent, backref=backref('children')
  def __init__(self, name, parent)
    self.name = name
    self.parent = parent
```

While working while my objects i do:

```
parent = Parent("my parent")
db_session.add(parent) # must be done for other reasons not relevant to the issue.
child = Child("my child", parent)
```

So far so good.
But prior to committing when I do the following I get a DB flush:

```
children = parent.children # using the backref causes a flush
```

Can this be avoided by changing how I define the backref/relationship?

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: A flush is a little expensive and in this case not required as the information is available in memory on the parent object, it shouldn't need to be flushed to be retrieved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Session.no_autoflush context manager should achieve what you want in a safe manner:

```
with session.no_autoflush:    
    parent = Parent("my parent")
    db_session.add(parent) 
    child = Child("my child", parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no SQLAlchemy expert, but it looks like SQLAlchemy can't populate the `parent.children` collection safely until both parent and children are flushed, since the primary and foreign keys used for their relationship is undefined until that happens. Maybe it even needs a query, since it can't know beforehand if all objects required to the relationship are in the current session.

I don't see any solution to that, and frankly, I don't see it as a problem. Your case smells a lot like premature optimization.

Anyway, I guess you can disable autoflush on your session by setting `session.autoflush = False` and back to `True` after leaving this point. Maybe it works, but you may run into unexpected situations.